# Android NDK applicaiton throws an error - Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am developing NDK based Android application. Right now I am studying using sample "HelloWorld" application. But it throws error each time. ***Please guide where it is wrong?***

P.S.: All my cpp files are inside jni folder only.

In LogCat, while debugging it says;

> 08-19 14:52:59.340: W/dalvikvm(469): No implementation found for
>   native
>   Lcom/example/myfirstndkapp/MainActivity;.concateneMyStringWithCppString
>   (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Here is the base code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstndkapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyFirstNDKApp");
        }

    private native String concateneMyStringWithCppString(String myString);

    private EditText tvGetValue = null;
    private TextView tvSetValue = null;
    private Button btnCallCPPMethod = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        String str = concateneMyStringWithCppString("OutputString");



        System.out.println("output : "+str);

        }
}
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := MyFirstNDKApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := CoreWrapper.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += Core.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := all
```

**Core.h and Core.cpp**

```
//
//  Core.h
#ifndef __MyFistNDKApp__Core__
#define __MyFistNDKApp__Core__

#include <iostream>
const char* concateneMyStringWithCppString(const char* myString);
#endif /* defined(__MyFistNDKApp__Core__) */

//  Core.cpp

#include "Core.h"

const char* CPP_BASE_STRING = "cpp says hello world to %s";

const char* concateneMyStringWithCppString(const char* myString) {
    char* concatenedString = new char[strlen(CPP_BASE_STRING) + strlen(myString)];
    sprintf(concatenedString, CPP_BASE_STRING, myString);
    return concatenedString;
}
```

**CoreWrapper.c**

```
//  CoreWrapper.c

#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "Core.h"

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL com_example_myfirstndkapp_MainActivity_concateneMyStringWithCppString(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring myString) {
    return env->NewStringUTF(concateneMyStringWithCppString(env->GetStringUTFChars(myString, 0)));
}

}
```

But while running it throws error on: *concateneMyStringWithCppString* line in MainActivity.java not even going inside. It says unrecognized one. Here is the error log:

[image]

While debugging inside that method: it navigates to UnsatisfiedLinkError class method:

```
public UnsatisfiedLinkError(String detailMessage) {
    super(detailMessage);
}
```

Comment: is the function header generated by `javah` or just typed in manually?

Comment: In jeneral, you should start with the hello-jni sample, it is in the NDK and it works. After you get it working, you can try to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that *CoreWrapper.h* class should be autogenerated using ***javah*** command. So each time we need to update a java class file and re-generate this jni file.

According to that jni generated header file, we require to create its cpp file where we can write our code logic.

I found tutorial on this [link](http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/04/tutorial-android-jni/) very useful. It helped me to find out my mistake.

Also it contains clear step by step information.

Hope this helps others who is looking for such.